# Applying conditions to read data blocks using Datastore (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, mapreduce

I would like to read a big data file in blocks using the datastore function in MATLAB. In this case, I would like to put a condition in order to read each data block.

For example: I have a Boolean column (0 or 1) and I want to read each data block with some size of elements, but only where the Boolean column is equal to 1 (one). I don´t want to eliminate these rows (with zero number) after reading the data block, in order to always have the same size of elements in each block. This process is to process data using the `mapreduce` approach.

In the mapper function I will handle with elements in each data block. I don't want elements with the number "1" in the Boolean column.

Example:
[image: read example]

Is this possible? Or will I have to find an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly control the number of rows read per block using the datastore function, or even the variables (columns) and data formats. However, the function does not permit this sort of data reading based on a condition.

I see two immediate alternatives:

-- Use datastore to obtain the full blocks of raw data and then perform the logic on the data in the mapper function. For example, it would be a one-liner to filter out the rows that have a value of 1 for the variable "Bool" in the mapper, before you do your primary calculations:

```
data = data(~data.Bool,:);
```

--  Preprocess the data using a simplified mapreduce calculation. Perhaps in the mapper you would filter the data the way you want, then pass it straight to an identity reducer. The result would be a new datastore containing only the data rows you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think this way will solve my problem.